# Android call a (not JNI) function from external .so library

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am struggling with this problem since few weeks I hope someone can help me.

I have created a C function wrapper in my Android app that impements the JNI export. I have also created a second .so library in order to call my original library but here I have a problem when linking with ndk-build. This is my code:

```
Android.mk

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := my_prebuilt_lib
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../jni/
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../jniLibs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/my_prebuilt_lib.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE    := myjni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := wrapper.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY += my_prebuilt_lib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This is the command I am using to build myjni.so:

```
ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=./ NDK_APPLICATION_MK=./jni/Application.mk
```

And I get this error:

```
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-16 is higher than android:minSdkVersion 1 in .//AndroidManifest.xml. NDK binaries will *not* be compatible with devices older than android-16. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md for more information.    
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : my_prebuilt_lib.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/liblocSDK4d.so
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: myjni <= wrapper.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libmyjni.so
jni/wrapper.cpp:24: error: undefined reference to 'hex2int(char)'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Looking into my_prebuilt_lib.so I can see the following declaration about the function I want to call:

```
00004c51 T hex2int(char)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you allowed to modify or wrap the library?

Comment: I just have the .so file, no code, so I cannot modify the library. What do you mean with wrap? From app side?

Comment: You can write a second .so library that links to the original library but *does* expose nice JNI-flavored functions for the functions you're trying to call.

Comment: Thanks Botje as you suggested I created the C wrapper and a second .so library. By the way I am now stuck cause of a linkage error. I'va updated the question with the details. Any idea?

Comment: Was the original library a C++ library? Then you need to reference the mangled version (either directly or a symbol alias) or write your wrapper in C++.

Comment: I tried as you suggested. I compiled the wrapper in c++ and also called the mangled version of the function (_Z7hex2intc), but the error is still present (I edited the question with the new error). Any other ideas? Thx for your support